# Can the enemy see your oracle lens?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I oracle lens inside a bush and there is no ward there, but there is an enemy close to the bush, will they see the oracle lens or is it only visible to allies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Farsight Wards, the animation from a Sweeper Drone cannot be seen in fog of war. If the enemy has no vision in the bush, they will not see the sweeping animation.

Comment: but they will see its effects, e.g. they will see the ward is disabled